# material-dialogs library:Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I am going to add [`material-dialogs`](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) library to my project but I get this error `Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3` This is `build.gradle`..Where is my mistake?Is sth wrong with my project?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.peomtime.tosca.peomtime"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.0'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
//Core
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.0.1'
compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1'

//compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
compile project(':Parallax')

compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'

compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.3.1'
}
```

thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have latest libraries installed in Android SDK Manager. For `appcompat-v7:21.0.3`, the packages need to be checked/updated are:

- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library

Also, it's recommended to fix your dependencies version rather than using `+` to get latest version:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I added this repo from Afollestad to my `build.gradle` (project, not model) and everything was resolved.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

[link](https://github.com/afollestad/material-cab)